# Synthesizing "Methyl 2-(2-oxopyrrolidin-1-yl)-2-phenylacetate"

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am a chemistry student, here I mapped out the steps one might take to synthesize Methyl2-(2-oxopyrrolidin-1-yl)-2-phenylacetate, a piracetam dirivitive. Please add any steps I might be missing and correct any mistakes. Thank you so much To synthesize Methyl 2-(2-oxopyrrolidin-1-yl)-2-phenylacetate (C16H15NO3) from Pyrrolidine (C4H9N) and phenylacetic acid (C8H8O2), here is the detailed step-by-step synthesis process:

1. Protection of Pyrrolidine:
       a. Dissolve Pyrrolidine (C4H9N) in an appropriate solvent, such as dry ether or dichloromethane (DCM).
       b. Add a protecting group to the Pyrrolidine's nitrogen atom, like the carbobenzyloxy (Cbz) group. Typically, benzyl chloroformate is used as the Cbz protecting agent.
   c. Cool the mixture to 0°C and add triethylamine (TEA) dropwise to react with the benzyl chloroformate.
       d. Allow the reaction to stir at room temperature for a few hours.
       e. Monitor the reaction using thin-layer chromatography (TLC) until completion.
       f. Work up the reaction by washing it with an aqueous solution, such as saturated sodium bicarbonate, followed by water, and then dry it over a drying agent like MgSO4.
       g. Filter and concentrate the mixture under reduced pressure to obtain Cbz-protected Pyrrolidine.
2. Activation of Phenylacetic acid:
       a. Dissolve phenylacetic acid (C8H8O2) in an appropriate solvent, like DCM.
       b. Add an activating agent such as oxalyl chloride or thionyl chloride along with a base such as TEA or pyridine in order to form Phenylacetyl chloride.
       c. Stir the mixture at room temperature until completion, which can be monitored by TLC.
   Coupling Reaction:
       a. To the solution of Cbz-protected Pyrrolidine from the first step, slowly add the Phenylacetyl chloride solution from the second step.
       b. Add an appropriate base, like TEA or DIPEA (N,N-diisopropylethylamine), to the mixture.
       c. Stir the reaction mixture at room temperature for a few hours and monitor completion using TLC.
3. Deprotection:
       a. Add a deprotecting agent such as Palladium on carbon (Pd/C) to remove the Cbz group.
       b. Hydrogenate the mixture under a hydrogen atmosphere while stirring for a few hours.
4. Oxidation:
       a. Filter and concentrate the crude product obtained in Step 4.
       b. Dissolve the crude product in an appropriate solvent, like DCM or ethyl acetate.
       c. To this solution, add an appropriate oxidizing agent like Dess-Martin periodinane (DMP) or Jones reagent (Chromium trioxide in acetic acid).
       d. Stir this reaction at room temperature for a few hours until completion (as monitored by TLC).
5. Purification:
       a. Quench the oxidation reaction with an aqueous solution such as saturated sodium bicarbonate or diluted brine solution.
       b. Separate layers and dry the organic layer with MgSO4.
       c. Filter and evaporate under reduced pressure to obtain the crude product.
       d. Purify the crude product using either column chromatography or crystallization.

[image]

Comment: I am confused by the reaction you are doing with the phenylacetyl chloride. You add CBZ- protected pyrrolidine and then hydrogenate. 1- why bother with protecting then deprotecting the pyrrolidine?  2 - this will give the pyrrolidinyl amide not substitution at the 2 position of the phenylacetate

Comment: You copy-pasted a recipe (source is an AI?) and are asking us to double check it. Not really how the site works.

Comment: No it's not AI. I read a couple different studies on the synthesis of similar molecules including Piracetam,  Phenylpiracetam,  and Methylphenidate and kind of mixed them up in a way that seems logical.  If you are referring to the photograph, that is from an app called King Draw Chemical structure. I have no idea if that's considered AI or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would start from the commercially available Methyl alpha-chlorophenylacetate (CAS 7476-66-6), react this with pyrrolidine and then oxidise the product with RuCl3/NaIO4 as reported Sharma & Ganesh  [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040403903030168)

Alternatively you could react Methyl alpha-chlorophenylacetate with the Methyl 4-aminobutyrate hydrochloride (also commercially available) in the presence of tertiary base to displace chloride then heat to cyclise to the pyrrolidone.